# Insert PHP Output Into Table

Tags: php, html

I've put together the code below that lists and allows me to delete members.

**Solution**

```
    <?php
    $db_host = 'hostname';
    $db_user = 'username';
    $db_pwd = 'password';

    $database = 'databasename';
    $table = 'tablename';
    // use the same name as SQL table

    if (!mysql_connect($db_host, $db_user, $db_pwd)) 
    die("Can't connect to database"); 

    if (!mysql_select_db($database)) 
    die("Can't select database"); 

    function sql_safe($s)  
{  
    if (get_magic_quotes_gpc())  
        $s = stripslashes($s);  

    return mysql_real_escape_string($s);  
}  

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')  
{  
    if (isset($_POST["submit"]))  
    {  
        if (isset($_POST['del'])) 
            $userid = intval($_POST['del']); 

        if (mysql_query("DELETE FROM {$table} WHERE userid={$userid}")) 
            $msg = 'The member who you selected has now been deleted!';  
        else 
            $msg = 'Could not delete the selected member'; 
    } 
}  
?> 
<html><head> 
<title>Save Photo(s) to Find</title>
<style type="text/css">
<!--
.style1 {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-family: Calibri;
}
.style2 {
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: Calibri;
}
.style3 {font-family: Calibri}
.style6 {font-size: 16px}
.style7 {font-family: Calibri; font-size: 16px; }
-->
</style>
</head> 
<body>
<p class="style7">
<?php 
if (isset($msg)) // this is special section for 
// outputing message 
{ 
?></p>
<p class="style7">
  <?=$msg?>
</p>
<?php 
} 
?>
<form action="<?=$PHP_SELF?>" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data"> 
<?php 
$result = mysql_query("SELECT userid, forename, surname, subscriptionexpiration FROM {$table} ORDER BY userid DESC"); 
if (mysql_num_rows($result) == 0) // table is empty 
echo 'There are no members to view'; 
else 
{ 
echo "<table>\n"; 
while(list($userid, $forename, $surname, $subscriptionexpiration) = mysql_fetch_row($result)) 
{ 
echo "<tr>\n" 
."<td><input type='radio' name='del' forename, surname value='{$userid}' /></td>\n" 
."<td><small>{$forename} {$surname}</small><td>\n" 
."<td><small>{$subscriptionexpiration}</small><td>\n" 
."</tr>\n"; 
} 
echo "<tr><td colspan=\"3\">"; 
echo '<input type="submit" value="Delete Selected Member" name="submit"/>'; 
echo "</td></tr>"; 
echo '</table>'; 
} 
?> 
<input type="hidden" name="action" id="action" /> 
</form> 
</body>
</html>
```

To make it a little easier for me, I'd like to be able to insert the outputted list into a table on my form with the first column containing the bullet point, radio button and name of the member and the last column to show the 'Subscription Expiration Date'.

I've tried to simply move the php script into the table columns but this simply doesn't work because I can't, or should I say, don't know how to incorporate the PHP and HTML elements together.

Comment: `don't know how to incorporate the PHP and HTML elements together.` What do you mean? You already did it in the code you posted...

Comment: maybe hes asking how to make it a table instead of a list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I eddited your code and replaced the list items (ul and il) with table tags (table,tr, and td).

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT userid, forename, surname, subscriptionexpiration FROM {$table} ORDER BY userid DESC"); 
if (mysql_num_rows($result) == 0) // table is empty 
echo 'There are no members to view'; 
else 
{ 
    echo "<table>\n";
    while(list($userid, $forename, $surname, $subscriptionexpiration) = mysql_fetch_row($result)) 
    { 
        echo "<tr>\n"
        ."<td><input type='radio' name='del' forename, surname value='{$userid}' /></td>\n"
        ."<td><small>{$forename} {$surname}</small><td>\n"
        ."<td><small>{$subscriptionexpiration}</small><td>\n"
        ."<td><input type=\"submit\" value=\"Delete Selected Member\" onclick=\"document.getElementById('action').value='delete'\" /><td>\n"
        ."</tr>\n";
    } 
    echo '</table>';  
}
```

Comment: Hi, many thanks for taking the time to reply to my post, it's basically what I'm looking for, but could you tell me please, what would I need to change so that there is just the one 'Delete Selected Member' button, with choice being made via the radio button. Kind regards.

Comment: @IRHM Just take that line out, and add it wrapped in it's own tr tag right before your `echo '</table>';` line (outside of the loop).

Comment: Hi @James, many thanks for taking the time to help out with this. I've done what I thought you were saying, but I've obviously done something wrong because I'm receiving the error:   
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING in line 83 whch is this line:"</tr>";
I've amended the code in my original post. Could you perhaps please have a look at this and let me know what I've done wrong. Kind regards

Comment: What James has done should work. If not let us know. If it does work please upvote us or accept answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can modify your code as follows, just switch out the list elements with table elements:

```
echo '<table>'; 
while(list($userid, $forename, $surname, $subscriptionexpiration) = mysql_fetch_row($result)) 
{ 
// outputing list 
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td><input type='radio' name='del' value='{$userid}' /> &nbsp;<small>{$forename} {$surname}</small></td>";
echo "<td><small>{$subscriptionexpiration}</small></td>";
echo "</tr>";
} 
echo '</table>';
```

Comment: Hi, many thanks for taking the time to reply to my post. It is greatly appreciated. Kind regards.

Answer (score 0):

I would leave the HTML like:

```
<form action="<?=$PHP_SELF?>" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data"> 
<?php  
$result = mysql_query("SELECT userid, forename, surname, subscriptionexpiration FROM {$table} ORDER BY userid DESC");  
if (mysql_num_rows($result) == 0) // table is empty  
echo 'There are no members to view';  
else  
{  
    echo "<table>\n"; 
    while(list($userid, $forename, $surname, $subscriptionexpiration) = mysql_fetch_row($result))  
    {  
        echo "<tr>\n" 
        ."<td><input type='radio' name='del' forename, surname value='{$userid}' /></td>\n" 
        ."<td><small>{$forename} {$surname}</small><td>\n" 
        ."<td><small>{$subscriptionexpiration}</small><td>\n" 
        ."</tr>\n"; 
    }  
    echo "<tr><td colspan=\"3\">";
    echo '<input type="submit" value="Delete Selected Member" name="submit"/>';
    echo "</td></tr>";    
    echo '</table>';   
}  
?>
<input type="hidden" name="action" id="action" /> 
</form>
```

And for my PHP:

```
<?php
$db_host = 'hostname';
$db_user = 'username';
$db_pwd = 'password';

$database = 'databasename';
$table = 'tablename';
// use the same name as SQL table

if (!mysql_connect($db_host, $db_user, $db_pwd)) 
    die("Can't connect to database"); 

if (!mysql_select_db($database)) 
    die("Can't select database"); 

function sql_safe($s) 
{ 
    if (get_magic_quotes_gpc()) 
        $s = stripslashes($s); 

    return mysql_real_escape_string($s); 
} 

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') 
{ 
    if (isset($_POST["submit"])) 
    { 
        if (isset($_POST['del']))
            $userid = intval($_POST['del']);

        if (mysql_query("DELETE FROM {$table} WHERE userid={$userid}"))
            $msg = 'The member who you selected has now been deleted!'; 
        else
            $msg = 'Could not delete the selected member';
    }
} 
?>
```

I took out the `exit()` because that's what was causing the page to stop loading (white screen).  I also took out your `onclick` event for the submit button because I wasn't sure what you were using that for, and it's not needed to perform this task.  If you were using it for something else, it can be put back in.

At the top, I just have it checking to see if the submit button was pressed.  Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: Hi, many thanks for looking at an replying to my post, it's truly appreciated. Kind regards.

Comment: @IRHM Did this answer your question, or are there still issues?

Comment: Hi @James, unfortunately this doesn't work. As soon as I add click the 'Delete Selected Member' button, the whole screen refreshes and becomes a blank web browser page. Then when I do a manual refresh the member whom I chose to delete, hasn't been deleted. Kind regards

Comment: Hi @James, many thanks for your continued help. I've added the full code to my original post. kind regards

Comment: many thanks for this, it works great. I re-introduced the message section, so upon deletion I get the correct message. I've added the final code to my original post. I really appreciate all your time and trouble. Kind regards